# Wrapper class template for std::map + std::list to provide a SequencedMap which retains insertion order

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, stl

Review on this draft please: clang-8 -std=c++17

Simple wrapper class template for std::map & std::list (or alternatively std:unordered_map & std::vector) for the purpose of "retaining insertion order". This is quite a frequently asked question, eg

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266179/c-stl-map-i-dont-want-it-to-sort/2267198

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053544/keep-the-order-of-unordered-map-as-we-insert-a-new-key/59100306#59100306

And the only answers are ["Boost::multi_index"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) or "roll your own with (unordered_)map + list|vector". The very slimline class template below attempts to put some structure to the latter for those who don't want to or can't include a huge sledgehammer.

A couple of utility print function templates and some simple use cases are included for illustration only. There are a couple of questions in the comments regarding a clean way to expose the iterators. And, more generally, how to expose the API of the private list/map containers to the public interface in a controlled way without writing wrappers for every function overload:

Same code as below [on goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mtgcxk):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class KeyT, class ValueT>
class SequencedMap {
  using MapT   = std::map<KeyT, ValueT>;
  using MapItT = typename MapT::iterator;

  using OrderValT = typename MapT::value_type*;
  using OrderT    = std::list<OrderValT>;
  using OrderItT  = typename OrderT::iterator;

public:
  std::pair<MapItT, bool> insert_or_assign(const KeyT& key, const ValueT& value) {
    auto ins_res            = map.insert_or_assign(key, value);
    auto [elem_it, was_new] = ins_res;
    if (was_new) order.push_back(&*elem_it);
    return ins_res;
  }

  MapItT find(const KeyT& key) const { return map.find(key); }

  ValueT& operator[](const KeyT& key) {
    // keep it simple. read or modify only. Not create!
    auto map_it = map.find(key);
    if (map_it == map.end())
      throw std::logic_error(
          "Warning! You are trying to create a SequencedMap entry using [] operator. Use "
          "insert_or_assign for safety!");
    return map_it->second;
  }

  OrderItT erase(const KeyT& key) {
    auto map_it = map.find(key);
    if (map_it == map.end()) return order.end();
    auto order_erased_it = order.erase(std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), &*map_it));
    map.erase(map_it);
    return order_erased_it;
  }

  // exposing the internal containers is not great, but need a clean way to expose their iterators
  // without too much code bloat. Preferable transparently change the MapT::value_type* to
  // MapT::value_type
  const MapT& getMap() const { return map; }
  const OrderT& getOrder() const { return order; }

private:
  MapT map;
  OrderT order;
};

// EOF class: Rest is demo usage code

template <class KeyT, class ValueT>
void print_in_insertion_order(const SequencedMap<KeyT, ValueT>& smap) {
  for (auto& pair_ptr: smap.getOrder()) {
    std::cout << pair_ptr->first << " -> " << pair_ptr->second << "\n";
  }
}

template <class KeyT, class ValueT>
void print_in_map_order(const SequencedMap<KeyT, ValueT>& smap) {
  for (auto& pair: smap.getMap()) {
    std::cout << pair.first << " -> " << pair.second << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {

  using Key   = std::string;
  using Value = int;

  SequencedMap<Key, Value> smap;

  // arbitrary ad-hoc temporary structure for the data (for demo purposes only)
  std::cout << "insert data...\n";
  for (auto p: std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>>{
           {"Mary", 10}, {"Alex", 20}, {"Johnny", 30}, {"Roman", 40}, {"Johnny", 50}}) {
    smap.insert_or_assign(p.first, p.second);
  }
  print_in_insertion_order(smap);
  std::cout << "\nsorted by key\n";
  print_in_map_order(smap);

  std::cout << "\nretrieve by known key\n";
  auto key = "Alex";
  std::cout << key << " -> " << smap["Alex"] << "\n";

  std::cout << "\nchange value by known key: Johnny++\n";
  ++smap["Johnny"];
  print_in_insertion_order(smap);

  std::cout << "\ndelete by known key: Johnny\n";
  smap.erase("Johnny");
  print_in_insertion_order(smap);
}
```

Done a really simple benchmark:

```
Bench
SequencedMap: insert 100,000=252.06ms
SequencedMap: iterate in insertion order=1.47723ms
SequencedMap: modify 100,000 in insertion order=103.497ms
SequencedMap: delete 10,000=7513.77ms
Map: insert 100,000=227.629ms
Map: iterate in map order=6.91042ms
Map: modify 100,000 in map order=90.8201ms
Map: delete 10,000=16.7736ms
```

All looks very reasonable, but we have a **problem on delete**, as I expected. Finding the pointer is a linear operation each time. So O(n^2) for the 10,000 deletions. Not sure how to solve that, except to make the datastructure more complicated. Eg a reverse pointer from the map entry back to the list. Feels like pointer spaghetti then.

So, maybe a different idea: Ditch the std::list altogether, and instead of `std::map<KeyT,ValueT>` we use a `std::map<KeyT,ValuePkgT>` where:

```
struct ValuePkgT
{
  ValueT value;
  next MapT::value_type*; // recursive type reference here?
}
```

In other words the map value contains a struct which makes a "simple linked list" out of the map elements. Then we could have SeqeuencedMap actually inherit from std::map (is that bad?) publish a second set of iterators...eg SequencedMap::ibegin()/iend() (i=insertion_order) which use the internal linked list to iterate?

Opinions? Problems? Wise to extend std::map?

**EDIT**: I have pursued these new ideas in another question, here:

[SequencedMap which retains insertion order - MKII](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233177/sequencedmap-which-retains-insertion-order-mkii)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reduce Lookups

`ValueT& operator[](KeyT key)` does 2 lookups, one in `map.count(key)` and one in `map[key]`. Using `map.find(key)` and then comparing the iterator against `std::end(map)` and then dereferencing it to return the value avoids that.

### Consistent Parameter Types

`ValueT& operator[](KeyT key)` takes `KeyT` by value while other functions use `const KeyT &`. There doesn't seem to be a reason for that and you should be consistent.

## Support Move-Only Types

Take inspiration from the standard. All versions of `std::map::insert_or_assign` take a `ValueT &&` while you take a `const ValueT &`. That means unlike the standard containers you do not support `std::unique_ptr` for example. I don't see anything else that is holding it back, so it's an easy improvement for minimal effort.

### Bonus: Use All The New Cool Features

(this one is not entirely serious)
In `insert_or_assign`

```cpp
    auto [elem_it, was_new] = ins_res;
    if (was_new) order.push_back(&*elem_it);
```

can be written as

```cpp
    if (auto [elem_it, was_new] = ins_res; was_new) {
        order.push_back(&*elem_it);
    }
```

I'm not sure it's better, but it's fancier. In theory it's better because it limits the scope of `elem_it` and `was_new`, but in practice in this case it just doesn't matter.

### Nitpicking

Some of your variables can be `const` such as `ins_res` and `map_it`.

### Extensions

You seem to want to keep it simple, so take these as suggestions of what could be done, not necessarily as part of the code review.

#### Transparent Comparators

It would be cool if you supported lookups that don't require to create a `KeyT`. For example `++smap["Johnny"];` unnecessarily creates a temporary `std::string`. `std::string` can compare to `const char *` already. See [transparent comparators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) and [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) for inspiration.

#### A Real Container

Maybe you could make `SequencedMap` [a real container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) which then allows its use in all the standard algorithms.

### When In Doubt Use `std::vector`

It's a good default container unless benchmarks show you need something else. `std::list` is legendary for its terrible performance in almost all circumstances, even the ones that sound like they should be faster such as removing an element from the middle.

Comment: Many thanks.  I will consider more carefully/ We were typing at same time. Can you have a look at benchmark - exposing the obvious delete/erase problem and the give some feedback on the idea of extending std::map and using the internal linked list?

Comment: I did the first 2. There were obvious improvements which I just missed. Removing the double loopup (which I was already doing during erase) sped up operator[] by 2x, obviously. Code and bench updated above.

Struggling with Move-only types. changing signature to `ValueT&& value` gives: `rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int`, and if I use `std::forward<ValueT>(value)` in the call below it doesn't get better: same error.

Not sure how to make that work.

Comment: is the idea of extending std::map bad?

Comment: I sorted the universal references for the move values. The my insert_or_assign mthods needs its own template header like this:

`template <class K, class V> std::pair<MapItT, bool> insert_or_assign(const K& key, V&& value) {     const auto ins_res            = map.insert_or_assign(key, std::forward<V>(value)); `

It can't rely on those types being templated at class level apparently for those params to be universal references.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and accept this answer. It was really helpful feedback for me, and I did all those things. Well, all except the more architectural stuff, because I had the above idea of a different datastructure which might solve delete performance and be less messy overall. 

I have finished my first draft of that solution, but will post this as a separate review questions.

Many Thx! @nwp